# hover in Jquery scroll not working

Tags: jquery

I have few images.We are using Jscroll.js.When i hover over the images a button is shown.hover works for first few images.but if i scroll down hover is not working for remaining images.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".chunkResultThumbContainer").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".chunkResultPreviewButton").css("visibility", "visible");
  })
  /*<%= this.ClientID%>_initJScroll();*/
});

$(".scroll").jscroll({
  loadingHtml: `<div style="clear: both; width: auto; margin: 50px;"> <
    img src = "../App_Themes/default/images/common/loading.gif"
  alt = "Loading"
  width = "24px" / > < /div>`,
  autoTrigger: false,
  nextSelector: "a.jscroll-next:last",
  contentSelector: ".scroll>div",
  debug: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/master/jquery.jscroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you put your code inside $(document).ready(function(){...}) ??

Comment: @marco yes ofcourse